# Recuperar posicion dentro de un CollectionView

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, swift3

Estoy desarrollando en IOS y soy primerizo.

La idea es que al iniciar el programa yo realizo un collection View de botones de la siguiente forma:

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    let taille = 45
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return taille
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let identifier = "item"
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.btnCollection.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        sender.description =
    }
```

Hasta ahora solo pinto de color el botón que le hago clic, lo que yo quiero saber es si hay la posibilidad de recuperar la posición dentro de la colección del botón que haga clic

si existe, ¿qué función utilizar?

Comment: trata de ser un poco mas claro...  pero al parecer necesitas la función del delegado didSelectItem... y dentro de la función .. colocas.....collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredVertically, animated: true) o tambien .centerHorizontally dependiendo tus necesidades y si no es esto, intenta ser un poco mas claro. saludos!

Comment: Si bueno es que al crear los botones les asigno una funcion la cual es .touchupinside, y llamo a la funcion buttonAction, y asi es como calmbio el background del boton, y quisiera saber si al momento de hacer clic puedo recuperar la posicion del boton dentro del CollectionView

Answer (score 1):

Si entendí bien lo que quieres lograr, la manera más rápida (aunque no me guste tanto) podría ser:

En la función del `dataSource`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

... agregar

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let identifier = "item"
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.btnCollection.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    // agregando como `tag` el indice del `row`...
    cell.btnCollection.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell
}
```

... de modo que posteriormente:

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    let index = sender.tag // obtienes el indice del `tag` ...
    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    sender.description =
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te estas complicando demasiado. La propia celda la puedes tratar como un boton. Tienes una función del UICollectionViewDelegate que es

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
print(indexPath)
}
```

Si se toca una celda se ejecuta este método y sabes que celda es porque te lo indica el indexPath.row